# How do I stop my text from overflowing the wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css

My the of counterbalanced overflows my wrapper, what should I do?

```
for (let opJ = 0; opJ < colCount.length; opJ++) {

  let name = ['Orderpicker', 'Counterbalanced Sit Down', 'Counterbalanced Stand Up', 'Pallet Truck Double', 'Pallet Truck Single', 'Reach Truck']
  let placeholder = certNames[4][1]


  if (opJ > 0) {
    placeholder = ''
  }

  if (obj[0][colCount[opJ]] != null) {
    divContents += "<div class='snapshotDisp cert_wrapper' style='width:" + divWidth + "%; float:left; '>" +
      "<div id='certOPR' class='snapshotCerts'>";
    certSt = certStyle(obj[0][colCount[opJ]]);
    console.log(divWidth)
    if (placeholder) {
      placeholder = certSt.icon + " " + placeholder
    }
    divContents += "<div align='center' class='" + certSt.class + "'>" +
      certSt.icon + name[opJ] /*  + certNames[aF.searchArrayForIndex(certNames,[[opCertsColumns[colCount[opJ]].toUpperCase(),0]])][1] */ + ": " + dC.formatDate(dC.SQLtoJS(obj[0][colCount[opJ]])) + "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "my the of counterbalanced" mean?

Comment: It seems like a question about CSS should be accompanied by HTML, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the style

```
overflow: auto;
```